# std::hash specialization remains unused by std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std, unordered-map

I am trying to extend `std::hash<T>` by supplying a specialization for `const char`, so that I can use `const char*` as key type in `std::unordered_map`.

This is what I tried:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct hash<const char*>
    {
        size_t operator()(const char* const& s) const
        {
           size_t h = 0;
           const char* tmp = s;

           while (*tmp)
              h = (h << 5) + h + (unsigned char)toupper(*tmp++);

           printf("hash of '%s' is (%ld)\n", s, h);
           return h;
        }
    };
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   const char* name1= "Mark Nelson";
   const char* name2= strdup(name1);

   std::unordered_map<const char*, int> map;

   printf("Insert (%s)\n", name1);
   map[name1]= 100;

   printf("Lookup (%s)\n", name1);
   printf("map[%s](name1) = %d\n", name1, map.find(name1) != map.end() ? map.find(name1)->second : -1);
   printf("Lookup (%s)\n", name2);
   printf("map[%s](name2) = %d\n", name2, map.find(name2) != map.end() ? map.find(name2)->second : -1);

   return 0;
}
```

What the output is:

```
Insert (Mark Nelson)
hash of 'Mark Nelson' is (121066894705597050)
Lookup (Mark Nelson)
hash of 'Mark Nelson' is (121066894705597050)
hash of 'Mark Nelson' is (121066894705597050)
map[Mark Nelson](name1) = 100
Lookup (Mark Nelson)
hash of 'Mark Nelson' is (121066894705597050)
map[Mark Nelson](name2) = -1
```

So to me it seems, `std::unordered_map` is using my provided hash implementation for both the insertion as well as the lookup. But for some reason, it does not find the value via `name2`, which seems like it is *still* using pointer comparison instead.

What is wrong here? I am using GCC 4.8.2, and the file was compiled with `g++ -std=c++11 main.cc`

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to define things in `std`.

Comment: @Lingxi I agree to a certain degree, but you NEED to overload templates in their specific namespaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need two things for an unordered map ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17017281/439599)):

1. A hash function
2. A comparison function for equality

So you have (1) which appears to work but then the map has to check the `const char *` for equality which devolves into a pointer comparison. To do this you can specify a custom comparator ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157687/using-char-as-a-key-in-stdmap)):

```
struct cmp_str
{
   bool operator()(char const *a, char const *b)
   {
      return std::strcmp(a, b) == 0;
   }
};

std::unordered_map<const char*, int, std::hash<const char *>, cmp_str> BlahBlah;
```

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented `std::equal_to<const char*>` and now it works as expected.

Comment: @user826955 You are only allowed to add specializations to `std` if it depends on a user-defined type, on pain of undefined behavior; neither your `hash<const char *>` nor `equal_to<const char *>` depends on one. Write your own hasher and comparator type rather than hijacking the standard ones.

Comment: Problem really is, that when I define my hasher and compare function, I agree that the same thing is achieved, but the usage gets way more uncomfortable if you intend to work with wrappers around the STL. e.g. `template <typename KEY, typename VALUE> class FoobarMar` as propietary implementation which *uses* the `std::map<KEY, VALUE>`. Exending `std` namespace will just make it work, while supplying functions will complicate the API (especially when using inheritance). Note that we generally do not use `std` namespace.