# Char * as key in a map C++

Tags: c++, hash

I am declaring a hash map like `map<char *, int> m`in my C++ program. But it was not working, so I followed the instructions from [Using char* as a key in std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157687/using-char-as-a-key-in-stdmap?rq=1)
and declared my map like `map<char *, int, cmp_str> m`. My program kind of looks like this

```
struct cmp_str
{   
    bool operator()(char const *a, char const *b)
    {   
        return std::strcmp(a, b) < 0;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   map<char *, int, cmp_str> m
   //Reading strings from a file 
   while( not end of file ) 
  {
     // char *str contains the line 
     if(m.find(str) != m.end()) {m[str]++; }
     else {m[str] = 1;}

  }
}
```

When I execute the program, if finds all strings but first  even if they are not inserted. When I tried using `map<string, int> m;`and converted `char *str` to `std::string` it works fine. But the input file is so large, it takes lots of time when I use string. I am not sure why it finds all strings when I use `char *`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Actually [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is not a *hash* map, it's a binary tree. If you want a hash you should use [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The code you posted is not *complete*.

Comment: This is incorrect duplicate

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `unordered_map<char *, int>` does not help

Comment: @CPP_NEW it helps if your intention is to use a hash map. But it does not help you to find your bug.

Comment: @user2079303 Yes, I tried both before posting this question and both did not help to find my bug. As I mentioned `std::string` works fine for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `map<char *, int, cmp_str> m` you cannot modify  that buffer after you inserted it to `std::map` as map does not copy data but pointer itself. When you use `std::map<std::string,int>` `std::string` does make a copy and that's why it works and it is slower. So you either need to manually create many buffers and store strings in them (and it will make your program slower) or use `std::string` which is proper and better way.

Comment: That is true. My strings have fixed length 50. Is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: @CPP_NEW maybe yes, but you need to explain what you are trying to achieve. Note if you decide to do that open new question.

Comment: I have a big file (~5GB) and I would like to store the count of each line in a hash table. Currently it takes around 10 minutes when I use `std::string`. I want it faster

Comment: @CPP_NEW it depends on data in your file. If there are many repetitions you may want to use radix tree - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree