# Same key(created with malloc) is added twice to map

Tags: c++, malloc, stdmap

How it is possible that the same key is added twice in map?
shouldn't it override the value in case the value was changed?

```
static map<const char *, int> lMap;
    const char * msg = "hhhhh";

    char *buf = (char *) malloc(5);
    strcpy(buf, msg);

    lMap.insert(make_pair(buf, 85));
    buf = (char *) calloc(5, sizeof (char));

    strcpy(buf, msg);
    lMap.insert(make_pair(msg, 85));

    cout << "size: " << lMap.size() << endl;
    map<const char *, int>::const_iterator it2;
    for (it2 = lMap.begin(); it2 != lMap.end(); ++it2) {
        cout << it2->first << " | " << it2->second << endl;
    }
```

printed result:

```
size: 2
hhhhh | 85
hhhhh | 85
```

Comment: As a side note: to be able to `strcpy` the string "hhhhh" you need 6, not 5 characters (5 for the `'h'`s and one for the terminating `'\0'`).

Comment: [Using char* as a key in std::map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157687/using-char-as-a-key-in-stdmap?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const char*` is a pointer. Comparing two pointers with `<` compares the addresses they point to. By default, `std::map` uses `<` to compare keys. Which means that two different `const char*` objects are distinct keys, even if they happen to contain the same data when interpreted as a nul-terminated string.

You're writing C++, not C. If you want a string, use `std::string`, not a pointer to something which will hopefully be a nul-terminated buffer.

Comment: lMap should contain object from different class, some of those classes are destroyed. if I'll add std::string to lMap from class that was destroyedwill the value of the string be saved on map, or it will be destroyedalso (scope issue?)

Comment: @15412s If you type the map as `std::map<std::string, int>`, it will store copies of those strings and will their sole owner, so you will not run into any scoping/premature destruction issues.

Comment: the following should be good for my case, right? std::string a="abc"; map.insert(make_pair(a,85));

Comment: @15412s Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the same key twice in the map. The key of the map is a `char *` (i.e. a pointer). You have two different pointer values that happen to point to identical strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
     static map<const char *, int> lMap;
```

The above statement maps `int` to `const char*` and not `int` to `value pointed by const char*`.

The map does not care what is pointed by the keys,it just cares that there are two different keys hence two entries are made.

Comment: I think that usually, one says that keys are mapped to values. Not the other way round.