# I am creating a binary file to insert a pair of int type and a structure in it and seeing the below given error . Kindly suggest

Tags: c++

**Error:**

```
/opt/x11r6/lib/gcc-lib/sparc-sun-solaris2.5.1/2.95.2/../../../../include/g++-3/stl_pair.h: In method `pair::pair(const char (&)[10], const journey_plan::contact_details &)':
/opt/x11r6/lib/gcc-lib/sparc-sun-solaris2.5.1/2.95.2/../../../../include/g++-3/stl_pair.h:68:   instantiated from `make_pair(const char (&)[10], const journey_plan::contact_details &)'
sonu.cpp:142:   instantiated from here
/opt/x11r6/lib/gcc-lib/sparc-sun-solaris2.5.1/2.95.2/../../../../include/g++-3/stl_pair.h:44: incompatible types in assignment of `const char[10]' to `char[10]'
/opt/x11r6/lib/gcc-lib/sparc-sun-solaris2.5.1/2.95.2/../../../../include/g++-3/stl_pair.h: In method `pair::pair(const pair &)':
sonu.cpp:142:   instantiated from here
/opt/x11r6/lib/gcc-lib/sparc-sun-solaris2.5.1/2.95.2/../../../../include/g++-3/stl_pair.h:48: assignment to `char *const' from `const char *' discards qualifiers
```

```
if(it == my_map.end())
{
    log_file<<"updateFile()::updating new Customer with : "<<UID<<":"<<temp.c_name<<" : "<<temp.j_count<<endl;
    my_map.insert(std::make_pair(UID,temp));
    myfile.write(UID,sizeof(UID));//<<UID<<":"<<c_name<<endl;
    myfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&temp),sizeof(temp));
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using char\* as a key in std::map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157687/using-char-as-a-key-in-stdmap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer since you did not post any of the source code. But it seems that you tried to use a char array as key to a map. That will not work. Use `std::string` instead.

`std::map<std::string,journey_plan::contact_details>`

Edit: You *can* use char arrays as keys, following this question: [Using char* as a key in std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157687/using-char-as-a-key-in-stdmap)