# How can I access the value of a map of LPCWSTR in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a map like so:

```
std::map<LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR> myMap = {
    {L"key1", L"value1"},
    {L"key2", L"value2"}
};
```

And I need to get the value from a variable of type `const wchar_t *` that will match in value with the key.
I tried

```
const wchar_t * key = L"key1";
wchar_t VALUE[350] = myMap[key];
```

but it tells me "initialization with '{...}' expected for aggregate object"

I also tried

```
wchar_t VALUE[350] = myMap.find(key)->second;
```

and I get the same build error
In addition, I am adding this `VALUE` to another `wchar_t` using `wcscat_s` which is why I don't have too much leeway with variable types.

I'm pretty sure my map is set up correctly, so how can I get the value from a key?

Comment: You can assign a pointer to a pointer, but not a pointer to an array. You need to use something like `wcscpy` which is the equivalent of `strcpy` for wide strings. Another perhaps better alternative is to use `std::wstring`.

Comment: from left you have array  and from right - pointer. of course error. you can use `PCWSTR value =  myMap[key];` you also can use `wcscpy_s` for make copy (are this need ?) `if (value = myMap[key]) wcscpy_s(VALUE, _countof(VALUE), value);` and this is pure *c++*, nothing related to *winapi*

Comment: Also worth noting that using `LPCWSTR` as a key for the map and not providing a custom comparator is just a bad idea. Without the custom comparator the key uniqueness and sorting is based on the pointer value and not the data it points to. I'd personally use `std::wstring` as the key instead. You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157687/using-char-as-a-key-in-stdmap

Comment: Just use `std::map<std::wstring, std::wstring>` and don't look back.  Putting raw pointers in a map is asking for trouble if the lifetime of the map outlives any of the pointers inside it.

Answer (score 0):

The value type in map is `const wchar_t*`, so you can assign it to a variable with the same type.Since c++11, we can use auto to deduce the type. Or use `std::wstring` if you want to copy the string.

All these assignment works

```cpp
  const wchar_t* val = myMap[L"key1"];
  auto* val2 = myMap[L"key1"];
  LPCWSTR val3 = myMap[L"key1"];
  std::wstring str_val = myMap[L"key1"];
```

To copy the string into an array, you need to call `wcsncpy`. May like this:

```cpp
  wchar_t VALUE[350];
  if (auto itr = myMap.find(L"key1"); itr != myMap.end()){
      wcsncpy(VALUE, itr->second, sizeof(VALUE)/ sizeof(VALUE[0]));
  }
```

It's error-prone and hard to maintain(The string's size may be larger than hardcoded 350, then only the front part of the string is copied), it's better to use `std::wstring`

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/33dxc7YTh)